# Как сделать подгрузку контента, как на мобильном

Tags: html, jquery

Всем привет, делаю мобильный сайт, подскажите как сделать через jquery подгрузку контента как на мобильном (зажимаем пальцем экран и проводим в низ, отпускаем и срабатывает ajax)
[image: Пример]

Answer (score 1):

Если используете мобильный браузер, то действие, которое вы описали там уже встроено (в большинстве современных браузеров) как обновление страницы (аналог F5/CTRL+R на десктопе).

Теоретически это можно сделать для браузеров, которые это действие не поддерживают. Но если вы используете браузер с его поддержкой, там все равно браузерное событие будет иметь более высокий приоритет, чем событие JS.